# Save an array of custom meta data in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, metadata

I have a custom meta box on `new-post` page which allows users to add photos. Each photo has its own meta data too. (title, url, description..etc).

So, is it possible to store these data as an array for one meta key in `wp_postmeta` table ?

Eg :-

```
$photo1 = array('title1','url1','desc1');
update_post_meta($post_id,'photo1',$photo1);
```

However, when I did this and looked at the `wp_postmeta` table. The value for key `photo1` was just "`Array`". So, what's the way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I tried your code and got this as the value of the key in the database: `a:3:{i:0;s:6:"title1";i:1;s:4:"url1";i:2;s:5:"desc1";}` which obviously looks like what you want.

Are you sure you're looking up the correct post in the db?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, when I did it, it saves in the database just with a string called "Array".. What's wrong  as you think ?

Comment: That's quite odd. Is your WordPress up to date? Any php errors?

Comment: Anyway, I myself used php function serialize() and serialized it manually :)